# dispatch_async in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode6, dispatch-async

I am really new to this programming language called `swift`.

I use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
});
```

this method for `async-dispatch-queue` in xcode 5.

I want implement it in swift language.

**how do i implement dispatch queue in or swift?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24034544/1402846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    println("hello")
})
```

However, when the last argument is a block, Swift lets you put it outside the parentheses.  This makes the function seem more like a control structure (like a `for` or `if` statement).  Thus you can do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those of you viewing this post three years later as I did, the Swift functions have been improved. Now you can write:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
    // Your code here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Xcode gives you an easy help with that....

Just type in

`dispatch_async` and hit enter... Than XCode gives you something like this...

```
dispatch_async(queue: dispatch_queue_t!, block: dispatch_block_t! () -> Void)
```

now take your mouse and double-click on `block: dispatch_block_t! () -> Void` and XCode will automatically change this to a working closure expression :-)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
     //Your Code here       
})
```